# With the differential equation $\dot{y}-\frac{1}{t}y = \sin t$, let $y(t)=\sum c_nt^n$. Determine the coefficients $c_n$ s.t. $y(t)$ is a solution.

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, summation

**Question**

> Consider the differential equation $\dot{y}-\frac{1}{t}y = \sin t, t>0$.
>
> Let $y(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nt^n$.
>
> Determine the coefficients $c_n$ such that $y(t)$ is a solution to the differential equation.

**The solution**

> $y(t) = c_1t - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)}\frac{1}{(2n-1)!}t^{2n}$

**Attempt**

We have
$$\begin{align}\dot{y} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_nnt^{n-1}  = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nnt^{n-1}\\\\
-\frac{1}{t}y = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nt^{n-1} \end{align}$$

Inserting this into the differential equation gives
$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nnt^{n-1} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nt^{n-1} = \sin t \\\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n-1)c_nt^{n-1} = \sin t \\\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n-1)c_nt^{n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{t^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}\end{align}$$

Multiplying with $t$ on both sides gives
$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n-1)c_nt^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{t^{2n}}{(2n-1)!} \end{align} $$

Since only even power of $t$ is on the right side, we can replace $n$ with $2n$ on the left side.

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(2n-1)c_{2n}t^{2n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{t^{2n}}{(2n-1)!} \end{align} $$

Equating the coefficients I arrive at
$$\begin{align}c_{2n} = \frac{1}{(2n-1)}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)!} \end{align} $$

Inserting this into $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{2n}t^{2n}$, differentiating, and inserting into $\dot{y}$ we get this equation

$$-\frac{1}{t}y(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{t^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)!}t^{2n-1}$$

Multiplying with $-t$ and simplifying this expression yields

$$y(t) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)}\frac{1}{(2n-1)!}t^{2n} $$

This almost matches the solution, but I can figure out where the term $c_1t$ appears from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I continue from the equation
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (n-1)c_nt^{n-1} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n - 1)!}t^{2n-1} \tag{$*$}$$
that you wrote. Expand both sides and just compare the coefficients:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&\color{blue}{(-1)c_0}&&t^{-1} + \color{green}
{c_2}&&t + \color{red}{2c_3}&&t^2 + \color{magenta}{3c_4}&&t^3 + \color{olive}{4c_5}&&t^4 + \color{teal}{5c_6}&&t^5 + \cdots\\
&= \color{blue}{0}&&t^{-1} + \color{green}{\frac{1}{1!}}&&t + \color{red}{0}&&t^2 + \color{magenta}{\frac{-1}{3!}}&&t^3 + \color{olive}{0}&&t^4 + \color{teal}{\frac{1}{5!}}&&t^5 + \cdots
\end{alignat*}
So we have:
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c}
c_0 = 0\\
c_3 = 0\\
c_5 = 0\\
\vdots\\
c_{2n-1} = 0\quad(n \geq 2)
\end{array}
\qquad\qquad
\begin{array}{c}
c_2 = \frac{1}{1!}\\
c_4 = \frac{-1}{3.3!}\\
c_6 = \frac{1}{5.5!}\\
\vdots\\
c_{2n} = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1).(2n-1)!}\quad (n \geq 1)
\end{array}
\end{align*}
Notice that equation $(*)$ doesn't give any condition for $c_1$, so it can be arbitrary. Therefore:
\begin{align*}
y(t) &= c_1t + \frac{1}{1!}t^2 + \frac{-1}{3.3!}t^4 + \frac{1}{5.5!}t^6 + \cdots\\
&= c_1t + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1).(2n-1)!} t^{2n}\\
&= c_1t - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1).(2n-1)!} t^{2n}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$\sin t= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \frac {t^{2n-1}} {(2n-1)!}$. Now compare coefficients. You get $(2n-1)c_{2n}=(-1)^{n-1} \frac 1 {(2n-1)!}$  and $c_n=0$ for $n$ odd, $n>1$. [I will let you see why $c_1$ can be arbitrary].

Comment: Yes, I think I see the way now. But what's the argument for changing $c_n$ into $c_{2n}$? How do we justify that change of index on the left side of the equation?

Comment: You have only odd powers of $t$ on the right side. On the left side you get $t^{2n-1}$ when $n$ is replaced by $2n$. @Carl

Comment: Great thank you! One last thing. We have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2n-1)c_{2n}t^{2n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{t^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$. How do we justify changing the summation index from $n=0$ to $n=1$ on the left hand side? Is it because there are no negative powers of $t$ on the right side?

Comment: It is simply because $(0)(c_0)=0$ so it makes no difference whether you have the term corresponding to $n=0$ or not. @Carl

Comment: But when do you multiply $c_0$ with $0$? Setting $n=0$ on the left side gives $(2\cdot 0 -1)c_0 t^{0-1} = -1c_0t^{-1}$, doesn't it?

Comment: I was taking about the reason for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_nnt^{n-1}  = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nnt^{n-1}$ @Carl

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. From you I get that $y(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{2n}t^{2n-1}$ where $c_{2n}=\frac{1}{2n-1} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$. But the solution says $y(t) = c_1t - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)}\frac{(-1)}{(2n-1)!}t^{2n}$

Comment: There is no condition on $c_1$ so it remains an arbitrary constant.  @Carl

Comment: Expand the summations on each side to five or six terms explicitly and see if that clarifies things.